Is Cs, Hg and Ga metallic but liquid at room temperatures
Cs, Hg and Ga are metallic conductors but are liquids at room temperature
is true or false

You can just google this

Is your concern what their melting point is, or if liquids can be metallic, or what?

The wording of this question is very unclear

Note that SE Q/As are not alternative, but complements to own searching and research.

Mercury is liquid at room temperature STP due to the incredibly weak interatomic forces in its metallic lattice. Mercury and bromine are the only elements in periodic table liquid at STP. Mercury - fair conductor
Gallium isn't but melts at temperatures just above room temperature (melts at 29.76 degrees). Your hand is 36 degrees approximately so gallium melts in your hand. Excellent conductor
Cesium is very similar to Gallium and also melts on your hand (melts at 28.5 degrees). Great conductor
There are posts on stack exchange for why they melt so low (cesium and gallium).
They are all metallic.

So gallium melts in your hand, while Caesium melts your hand

@IanBush Altered for clarification / clearness

Sorry - no need to alter, it's just  a (very poor) joke regarding the different reactivity of Ga and Cs.

oh lol its fine

Mercury has interatomic interactions - atoms are bound by vdW interaction.

Also name of elements aren't proper nouns in English.
